# Mirroring the value of an int

Tags: c

I wonder if the following is possible in c

```
int a; int b;
a = somefunc();
lots of stuff here that change the value of a
```

What I want is to mirror the value of `a` at all times, stored in the variable `b`. `a==b`

I want to avoid doing `b = a` after calling `somefunc()` and every other time I do something with `a`. Adds clutter to the code.

Comment: haacks gave a good answer on using pointers to do this, but I'm curious why you need to do it at all. If you always want b to have the exact same value as a, why not just use a whenever you would use b? Another option (that affects the entire file scope) is to use a macro: `#define b a`, which will effectively replace all b's with a's at compile time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare `b` as a pointer to `int` and assign the address of `a` to `b`

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
```

Now `b` is pointing to the location of variable `a`. As long as `b` points to `a`, `*b` (represents the object to which `b` currently points) is an alias of `a`.